# TemplateDoesNotExist but it exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-templates

Python 2.7 & Django 1.10
my template exist but i do somesing wrong!

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /basicview/2/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
This is template_two view!
</body>
</html>

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicview/2/
Django Version:     1.10.1
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
This is template_two view!
</body>
</html>

Exception Location:     /home/i/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /home/i/djangoenv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.11
Python Path:    

['/home/i/djangoenv/bin/firstapp',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/i/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg']

Server time:    Пт, 23 Сен 2016 15:43:30 +0000
```

**settings.py** (os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'templates', or /home/mainapp/templates) not working..

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**article/views.py** my def looks like:

```
def template_two(request):
    view = "template_two"
    t = get_template('myview.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'name': view}))
    return render(request, html, {})
```

My file:

```
mainapp/mainapp/settings.py
mainapp/mainapp/article/views.py
mainapp/templates/myview.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are manually rendering your template and using the `render` shortcut at the same time. Your `get_template` is working, but when you call `render(request, html, {})`, Django is treating `html` as the filename, and looking for a template file named `<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>...`.

You should either render the template manually:

```
def template_two(request):
    view = "template_two"
    t = get_template('myview.html')
    html = t.render({'name': view})  # Note you should use a plain dictionary, not `Context` on Django 1.8+
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Alternatively, it's simpler to use the `render` shortcut.

```
def template_two(request):
    view = "template_two"
    return render(request, "myview.html", {'name': view})
```

You should also change your `DIRS` setting back to use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`. Using the string `'templates'` is not going to work.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that you put your temlates in your app.

Your file will then be here:

```
mainapp/mainapp/templates/myview.html
```

Please make sure you add `mainapp` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'mainapp',
]
```

Comment: no my templates is in mainapp not in mainapp/mainapp

Answer (score 2):

In your *settings.py* you have `'DIRS': ['templates'],`

And path to your template is `mainapp/templetes/myview.html`

You have typo `templetes != templates`. Rename folder with templates to `templates`.

Comment: same error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /basicview/2/

myview.html

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** copy path of your Template.

[image]

**Step 2:** past copy path in **DIRS** in your setting.py >> "Template"

[image]

> **its work for me**

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.1.7, I just restarted the server "python manage.py runserver", it worked.
My entry in settings.py is

```
        TEMPLATES = [
            {
                'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
                'DIRS': [],
                'APP_DIRS': True,
                'OPTIONS': {
                    'context_processors': [
                        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                        'django.template.context_processors.request',
                        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    ],
                },
            },
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

as of 05/05/2021, everything I had to do to resolve this error added the full path to the "DIRS" in settings.py

example:

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [r'the path to the templates folder here'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make **"DIRS"** blank in **"TEMPLATES"** in **"settings.py"**. **Django** will find **"templates" folder** automatically:

```py
# "mainapp/settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'DIRS': [], # Here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```